# Laravel project not showing in localhost: "Composer detected issues in your platform...."

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

When I want to see my Laravel project in localhost, I get the following error message.

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".

My terminal PHP version is 8.0.2, and my MAMP PHP version is 8.0 (no higher version is available, it has always worked like this). I don't know what else to do. I have already put my composer.json and .lock files at 8.0.2 PHP.

Comment: Well, what do you expect us to do? If your php version is lower than what composer expects, then that won't work...

Comment: Please share more details. Why not use the same PHP version in both environments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the following to install/update commands if you have an invalid PHP version or are missing a PHP extension. This command will update your dependencies while ignoring any PHP version or extension requirements.

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: this is what worked for me

`php8.1 /usr/local/bin/composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`